# AlarmManager повтор каждый день в опредленное время

Tags: android, java

Что нужно передать в alarmManager, чтобы он, к примеру, выполнялся каждый день в 19:00?

```
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AlarmManager.setRepeating(<Флаг>, <Когда выполнить?>, <Через какой промежуток?>, <Что выполнить?>);

Флаг - ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC, или RTC_WAKEUP

Флаги: 
ELAPSED_REALTIME - действие выполниться только при следующем пробуждении устройства после времени срабатывания, или во время срабатывания, если устройство в это время не спало. Отсчет времени для <Когда выполнить?> ведется с момента включения устройства   (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())

ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP -  точно, как ELAPSED_REALTIME, только устройство будет пробуждено в момент срабатывания, и нужное действие сработает сразу.

RTC - точно, как ELAPSED_REALTIME, только отсчет ведется с "начала времен"(System.currentTimeMillis())

RTC_WAKEUP - точно, как RTC, только устройство будет пробуждено в момент срабатывания, и нужное действие сработает сразу.

<Когда выполнить?> - в милимекундах в зависимости от <Флаг>

<Через какой промежуток?> - в милимекундах

<Что выполнить?> - PendingIntent, который надо выполнить

Comment: а как сделать чтобы он каждый день выполнял в 19 00, 
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() не знаю что оно дает, но выполняет тогда когда загрузка началась

Comment: 1) прочитать еще раз мой ответ    
2) понять, какой флаг нужно использовать    
3) расчитать, что вставить вместо <Когда выполнить?> в зависимости от выбранного флага    

Я обожаю работать за других, поэтому я сделаю это за вас:    
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + <сколько милисекунд осталось до 19:00>, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);