# Android обновление списка по времени

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Через ретрофит получил список данных, сохранил файл на карту памяти, как мне сделать что бы файлы обновлялись каждый час?

активити

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



TextView name;
TextView city;
TextView adress;
TextView phone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.department_name_id);
    city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city_id);
    adress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adress_id);
    phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone_id);


    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        try {
            // прочитал файл "name.dep" из Download
            FileInputStream fIS =
                    new FileInputStream(
                            new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "name.dep")
                    );
            ObjectInputStream oIS = new ObjectInputStream(fIS);
            ArrayList<Department> dep = (ArrayList<Department>) oIS.readObject();
            oIS.close();
            listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,dep));
            Log.v("MyApp","File has been readed");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("MyApp","File didn't readed");
        }
    }




    Retrofit.getDepartment(new Callback<List<Department>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Department> departments, Response response) {

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                try {
                    // записал файл "name.dep" в Download
                    FileOutputStream fos =
                            new FileOutputStream(
                                    new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "name.dep")
                            );
                    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    os.writeObject(departments);
                    os.close();
                    Log.v("MyApp","File has been written");
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("MyApp", "File didn't write");
                }
            }

            listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, departments));


        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


}


class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Department> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Department> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textNameofDepartment = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.department_name_id);
            holder.textCity = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.city_id);
            holder.textAdress = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.adress_id);
            holder.textPhone = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.phone_id);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        Department department = getItem(position);
        holder.textNameofDepartment.setText(department.getName());
        holder.textCity.setText(department.getCity());
        holder.textAdress.setText(department.getAddress());
        holder.textPhone.setText(department.getPhone());


        return rowView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        public TextView textNameofDepartment;
        public TextView textCity;
        public TextView textAdress;
        public TextView textPhone;
    }



}
```

}

Ретрофит

```
public class Retrofit {



private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api";
private static ApiInterface apiInterface;

interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/pboffice?json&city=&address=")
    void getDepartment(Callback<List<Department>> callback);


}

static {
    init();
}

private static void init() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
    apiInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
}

public static void getDepartment(Callback<List<Department>> callback) {
    apiInterface.getDepartment(callback);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно [использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/394959/17609) `AlarmManager`. В нём задать время в кое всплывёт в системе ваш `Intent`, коий вы можете поймать с помощью `BroadcastReceiver`, в коем сможете запустить задачу обновления ваших данных.

Comment: Так броадкаст ловит же изменения в девайсе, что именно для аларма указывать в манифесте?

Comment: @Azarnoy, Аларм можно, например, в активити/фрагменте установить, а ловить посылаемые им Интенты надо `BroadcastReceiver`-ом, коий, да, надо в манифесте прописать.